# In what cases would ignoring the spread operator in useReducer cause bugs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In most of the `useReducer` examples I saw, the spread operator has been used to preserve states. However, in all of my practices, ignoring it has never caused any problems. It seems like the reducer is able to preserve the state itself without the spread operator. Check the following example:

```
const initialState = {
    color: 'black',
    bgColor: 'white'
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'dawn':
            return {
                ...state,
                color: 'white',
                bgColor: 'purple'
            }
        case 'reset':
            return initialState
        default:
            return {
                state
            }
    }
}

const UseReducerColorSetter = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const { color, bgColor } = state;
    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ color: `${color}`, backgroundColor: `${bgColor}` }} className='card'>
                Hello
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'dawn' })}>Dawn mode</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'reset' })}>Reset</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

In this example, removing `...state` does not cause any problems, no state change, no console error, etc.

In this question I asked: [is it necessary to use the spread operator in useReducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64937984/is-it-necessary-to-use-the-spread-operator-in-usereducer/64938108#64938108), ignoring the spread operator caused problems in `useState`, but still no issues with `useReducer`.

Can someone provide me with some examples of ignoring the spread operator causing issues in `useReducer`? Can a reducer preserve state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a running example showing that if you do not replace all object properties in a reducer, they will be lost. Compare the console logged initial values with the printed result.

```js
const initialState = {
  color: "black",
  bgColor: "white"
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "dawn":
      return {
        bgColor: "purple" // Updated to only return one property to illustrate the problem
      };
    case "reset":
      return initialState;
    default:
      return {
        state
      };
  }
};

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Initial: ", state)
    dispatch({ type: "dawn" });
  }, []);

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(state)}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Notice the [signature of the reducer function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) `(state, action) => newState`. This function returns the new state. So whatever you `return` from the reducer is the new state value in its entirety. This means without spreading the root state object, you will lose any values not explicitly set in the new object.

To answer your question directly, not spreading the previous state on reducer updates will cause bugs when your state is an array or object, and you do not replace every value in that structure manually.

If you **always** set each object property or return the previous state, you will never encounter a bug. This is the scenario you have given in the question, and is why it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case it would not affect or create issues because you are changing the state values (color and bgColor), if you had a case that only changes color for example, ignoring the spread operator would leave the state without a bgColor value, this can cause issues if your app is expecting to have a bgColor at all times.

```
 case 'blue':
            return {
                color: 'blue',
            }
```

Comment: I tried your code and it did not cause issues, text color changed to blue and reset worked fine.

Comment: Yes just double checked, it looks like it keeps the old unchanged properties